# Is there a difference between extending ServiceTracker class and implementing ServiceTrackerCustomizer interface when tracking OSGi services?

Tags: java, osgi, modularity, osgi-bundle

I am creating some OSGi bundles. They register services and also get (and of course use) each other's services.

I decided to use `ServiceTracker` instead of Declarative Services.

As I was searching for information about this I found two approach of tracking services.

The first one is creating an own tracker class for each service, which **extends** the `ServiceTracker` class and overrides the methods that need to be overridden. Then in the activator class creating a new instance of this tracker class giving the bundle context to it and open it for tracking.

The other approach is creating a tracker class for each service, which **implements** the `ServiceTrackerCustomizer` interface and overrides the methods that need to be overridden. Then in the activator class creating a new instance of the `ServiceTracker` class giving to it the bundle context, the name of the service that needs to be tracked **and** a new instance of our customizer class. Then open it for tracking.

Are there any differences between the two approaches? I would say no. In the [ServiceTracker javadoc](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/util/tracker/ServiceTracker.html) I can see that the `ServiceTracker` class also implements the `ServiceTrackerCustomizer` interface.

Could you please tell me the pros and cons on both the approaches? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my reasons:

Sub-class ServiceTracker if

- You want to hard-code the constructor parameters of the super class. E.g.: Hardcode the type or filter. In this case it would not look nice if all of the users should know what filter the tracker should be instantiated with
- You want to override (wrap) open, close or other functions of ServiceTracker
- You want to extend the functionality of *ServiceTracker*. E.g.: By having an implementation that pre-filters service objects based on Java Generics equality

Implement the interface if:

- You expect to switch to other *ServiceTracker* implementation in the future. *ServiceTracker* is an add-on for OSGi core, it is only part of the core spec since 5.0.0. Other, more effective implementations can be created in the future
- You do not want to decide which constructors you want to override as the parameters are flexible from the view point of your business logic. Probably there will be more constructors of the standard ServiceTracker class in the future. If you sub-class it, your class will not support those constructors
- You want to sub-class from another class in the implementation of *ServiceTrackerCustomizer*

Do not use *ServiceTracker* directly if

- Declarative Services or other [Component Model](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Component_Models_Overview) helps you writing cleaner  and more stable code

Answer (score 1):

In over 12 years of developing with OSGi I don't think I have ever written a single `ServiceTrackerCustomizer`. IMHO it's just more convenient to directly subclass `ServiceTracker` and leave the customizer parameter `null`.

One simple reason it's easier to subclass is that you don't need to provide an implementation of the `modifiedService` method, which is rarely needed.

Functionally, however, the result will be the same so it's very much a personal preference.